# LINQ query to Group and get Sum

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following query which joins a collection of RailwayStation objects and ExpenditureData objects joined by StationId and I am trying to get the top 10 StationCargoCodes (a property on the Station object) and also select the Sum of the ExpenditureCost for the top 10 but I cannot get the correct syntax:

```
var data = (from s in stations join e in expenditureData on s.stationId 
equals e.StationId 
orderby e.expenditureAmount descending 
select s)
.Sum(e => e.expenditureAmount)
.GroupBy(n => n.StationCargoCode)
.Take(10);
```

What LINQ would I need to do the grouping and sum for this?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `.Sum(e => e.expenditureAmount)`?

Comment: Sum is a reduction. It will return a single amount and terminate the query. You can encapsulate the common part of the query as a method and then call .Sum and (GroupBy->Take) separately

Comment: yes, have updated it :) but the syntax is stil not correct I think.

Comment: Second poster is right, you can't group by on the result of sum, that will be a scalar value.

Comment: @Novaterata thank you for your comment. But that is how I have tried to construct the query by putting sum, groupby and take at the end separatley, but it doesn't work with that syntax.

Comment: They aren't separate. Each of those is a method call on the results of the previous

Comment: Ok, I'm confused. Do you need both the Top 10 codes AND the Sum for the entries of the top 10 codes? Or just the sum.

Comment: BTW you can use the group clause in the query https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384063.aspx

Comment: @Novaterata basically I need the output to be:  `StationCargoCode | 599, StationCargoCode | 580, StationCargoCode | 520  `etc ... in order of highest ExpenditureAmount to lowest for top 10.

Comment: Then you need to update the question to make that clear. The fact that some people understood your intentions was not because of the way the question was asked.

Answer (score 2):

```
var query = from s in stations
            join e in expenditureData
                on s.stationId equals e.StationId into se
            group se by new
            {
                s.StationCargoCode, ExpenditureCostSum = se.Sum(x => x.ExpenditureCost)
            } into g
            orderby g.Key.ExpenditureCostSum descending
            select g.Key;

var top10 = query.Take(10).ToList();
```

Comment: @Novaterata I dont think so. I think the OP wants the top 10 `StationCargoCode` along with their sum. Getting the top 10 `StationCargoCode` will not be very useful since they are just codes. Maybe I am mistaken so we will to see what the OP says.

Comment: basically I need the output to be: StationCargoCode | 599, StationCargoCode | 580, StationCargoCode | 520 etc ... in order of highest ExpenditureAmount to lowest for top 10.

Comment: @Theomax yes that is what my answer is doing. So what is the problem?

Comment: In that case than this is very close to what you want. but instead of ordering where it is being ordered you need to extract the sum in a `let sum = g.Sum(x => x.expenditureAmount)` then `order by sum` then instead of `select g` you `select new { StationCargoCode = g.Key, Sum = sum }`

Comment: @CodingYoshi it nearly works but for the line order by g.Sum(x => x.expenditureAmount) descending it does not allow for selecting x.expenditureAmount, instead it can only select from the other object which doesn't have that property.

Comment: @Theomax, What "other object" are you talking about? As far as we know there is only one object type, whatever ExpenditureData is. Is there something else you are leaving out?

Comment: The Staion object has the StationCargoCode property, and the ExpenditureData object has the ExpenditureAmount property.

Comment: @Theomax see my edit. It should give you everything you need.

Comment: @CodingYoshi it looks like the syntax: select new {StationCargoCode = g.Key, 
            ExpenditureCostSum = ExpenditureCostSum) }; may be what I didn't understand. I will try this code later :)

Comment: Oh I'm stupid of course there are 2 objects it's a join

Comment: @novaterata no you are not. You are actually very helpful and helped me with this answer

Comment: it's possible you need to create a stationAndExpenditure obj that you group by instead of just station

Comment: It seems what is simple to do in SQL is not possible with linq to group and sum. The line: `let expenditureCostSum = g.Sum(x => x.ExpenditureCost)` does not allow for ExpenditureCost  to be selected, it only allows properties in the other object (Station) rather the object that contains ExpenditureAmount to be selected. Perhaps the data needs to be joined first into one object? like this: `var joinedData = (from s in stations join e in expenditureData on s.stationId 
equals e.StationId select s).Distinct(); `

Comment: @Theomax you take too long to reply to messages...this should not have taken this long. Please see edit.

Answer (score 1):

your periority is wrong my friend.
think about it, you get the top 10 and then do  the sum operation. 
the code above get the sum of all and then you take the last 10.
Your code should be more like this instead

```
var data = (from s in stations 
join e in expenditureData on s.stationId equals e.StationId 
orderby e.expenditureAmount descending 
select s)
.GroupBy(n => n.StationCargoCode) // you may need to do Select(x=> x.First()) if you want to have only distinct
.Take(10) // take the top 10 eg from 0 to 10
.Sum(e => e.expenditureAmount) // then Do sum on the result which will be the top 10
```

Comment: is it possible to modify this query to select the SUM of the expenditure amounts for the top 10 stations?

Comment: isnt that what this is doing ? and im sorry i did not noticed orderby e.expenditureAmount descending you should not need to Reverse